# Error found when loading /home/user/.profile

Tags: ubuntu

При включении linux ubuntu вылазит ошибка:

> Error found when loading /home/user/.profile
>
> /home/user/.profile: строка 28: /bin/brew: Нет такого файла или каталога[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так и в чём вопрос? Вам написали в чём ошибка и даже написали где

Comment: Откуда у вас вообще brew в линуксе? Это же маковская фигня

Answer (score 0):

в файле .profile надо убрать лишние повторы, у меня это было с 28 строки - 31